# UIButton which looks like UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIBarButtonItem with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375372/uibarbuttonitem-with-image)

I want to create a `UIButton` which looks similar to a `UIBarButton` item (i.e. with rounded corners and gradient background) and add it to my View:

[image: Gradient button]

How can I do this?

Comment: http://spyrestudios.com/how-to-use-custom-uibutton-graphics-for-iphone-applications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    _btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 1500, 100, 200)];
    _btn1.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _btn1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [_btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you want draw the layer by yourself you can have a look at the [MAConfirmButton](https://github.com/mikeahmarani/MAConfirmButton)

Comment: THis is the code I wrote and it's not working, I still get a button with 90 degree corners. Could you please take a look at the image I posted in the question, that is the type of button I want to have. thanks.  

' UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen Shot .png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,50,25)];
    [self addSubview:btn];'

Comment: @pseudonym_127 to set the 'roundedness' of corners, set the `button.layer.cornerRadius` property. Larger number => More rounded.
You'll need to `#import <Quartzcore/Quartzcore.h>` to do that though.

Comment: @pseudonym_127 yes you should use cornerRadius

Comment: not working for some reasons ...

Comment: Thanks but if you look carefully, the outlook is still not exactly the same as to the button I attached to the question. seems like shadows or smth. else is missing..