# UIBarButtonItem with Image

Tags: ios

I want to create a `UIBarButtonItem` that looks exactly like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use uicustom button with such image for UIBarButtonItem. And if the numeric is variable then you can add an UILabel over the button. Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a utility method to add left bar button for any of your view. Make obvious changes to get a right bar button.

```
+(void)setMenuButton:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
UIImage *listIcon= [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"];
UIButton *rightBarButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[rightBarButton setBackgroundImage: listIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightBarButton addTarget: viewController.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(barButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
rightBarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30);
rightBarButton.tag = BAR_BUTTON_TAG;
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: rightBarButton];
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *button30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_textured_30"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:button30 forState:UIControlStateNormal
    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

create a custom button and use it ie; `[self.navController.leftBarButtonItem = customButton];`