# How to change UINavigation Back Button to an image?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, navbar

So I have these images that are used for a custom Nav bar and items, they look like this.Currently I have the custom nav bar set up, however I don't know how change the default "back" button to the back button image below, this is what I want to know? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note: I am using storyboards. Thanks

This is the nav bar:

[image]

This is my back button that i don't know how to imlpement.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If you want add back button to UINavigation try this:**

**First create back button:**

**1. If you don`t need to back action:**

```
        UIBarButtonItem *myBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
```

**2. If you want to create back button with image then try this:**

```
    UIBarButtonItem *myBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage
    imageNamed:@"yourImageName"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil
    action:nil]
```

**3. If you want to create back button with image and action then try this:**

```
    UIBarButtonItem *myBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage
    imageNamed:@"yourImageName"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
    action:@selector(goBack:)]

    - (void)goBack:(id)sender {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

**After created back button add it to NavigationBar:**

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBackButton;
```

**Implementation of logic "Add back button" you can put in viewDidLoad method:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBackButton;
}
```

And you need to more information see this: **[UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

**Here more examples for you:**

- [How to Customize Navigation Bar and Back Button](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-bar-back-butto/)
- [UINavigationController with a Custom Back-Button (Image)](http://www.dev-smarter.com/uinavigationcontroller-with-a-custom-back-button-image/)
- [Custom back button with a Navigation Controller](http://mpatric.com/2011-05-21-custom-back-button-with-a-navigation-controller)

---

- [how to create back button in navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057327/how-to-create-back-button-in-navigation-bar)
- [Customize the Back Button of UINavigationItem in the Navigation
  Bar](https://coderwall.com/p/kzdo7g)
- [UINavigationBar Back Button with images](http://iphonedevcentral.blogspot.com/2010/10/uinavigationbar-back-button-with-images.html)

Comment: Robert sorry for that late answer your question. I'm logged into the stackoverflow now. See my last edited answer and look my added extra links. If these answer and examples can't help you, then send it to my e-mail your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:target action:action;]
self.navigationItem.rightButtonItem = back;
```

For more info about UIBarButtonItem, go [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Also try to search next time for [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377469/611055) before posting new.

Comment: Where do I implement this?

Comment: You can implement this in -viewDidLoad method